# How to markup alternate part numbers for Schema.org Product?

Tags: schema.org

We have been using schema.org to markup our products on the web with metadata.

We have a system where we have alternate part numbers for products and customers want to be able to search for any of the alternate part numbers.

Using schema.org or GoodRelations how should we mark up alternate part numbers? We think we should have one page on the web per part on not one page per alternate part number but we do want Google and Bing to be able to find and understand our alternate part number semantically?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "product part" concept can be represented in GoodRelations by an object property isAccessoryOrSparePartFor (http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#isAccessoryOrSparePartFor) that is allowed on a class ProductOrServiceModel (http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#ProductOrServiceModel)

I don't have an answer on whether Google or Bing take this property into account in their current implementation. This is a moving target and perhaps your best option is to give it a try.